# How to iterate over a multidimensional string array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a 2d string array (at least I think it is called a 2d array):

```
var target = new string[var1,var2];
```

Now I want to convert it to `List<List<string>>`:

```
var listlist = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var row in target)
{
  var newlist = new List<string>();
  foreach (var el in row)
  {
    newlist.Add(el);
  }
  listlist.Add(newlist);
}
```

But row has a type is `string` and `el` has type is `char`.

I can't understand why `el` is not a `string`? What's wrong?

Comment: When you enumerate a `string[]`, you get `string`. When you enumerate a `string`, you get `char` because it implements `IEnumerable<char>`. What point didn't you understand?

Comment: If this behavior is correct so how can i create a 2d string array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `foreach` interates over a `string[,]` like it is a `string[]`. It doesn't split in rows.

If you do want to handle 'rows' and 'columns' those separately, you have to get the dimensions of the array, using the [`GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var target = new string[var1, var2];

var listlist = new List<List<string>>();
for (int x = 0; x < target.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    var newlist = new List<string>();
    for (int y = 0; y < target.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        newlist.Add(target[x, y]);
    }
    listlist.Add(newlist);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

```
    static void SoStrList()
    {
        int var1=10, var2=7;
        var target=new string[var1, var2];

        var listlist=new List<List<string>>();

        for(int i=0; i<var1; i++)
        {
            var row=new List<string>();
            for(int j=0; j<var2; j++)
            {
                row.Add(target[i, j]);
            }
            listlist.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `for` loop instead of `foreach`

```
        var target = new string[2, 2];
        target[0, 0] = "a";
        target[0, 1] = "A";
        target[1, 0] = "b";
        target[1, 1] = "B";

        var listlist = new List<List<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < target.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            var newlist = new List<string>();

            for (int j = 0; j < target.GetLength(1); j++)
                newlist.Add(target[i,j]);

            listlist.Add(newlist);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
foreach (var row in target)
```

You already have first element of your 2d array, and foreach take all chars of this elements

Answer (score 0):

well ... string is array of chars. 
And this confusion is what you get from using keyword `var` for almost everything. Its not javascript.

Secondly : You need to go for something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < target.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < target.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                your manipulation with strings
            }
        }
```

but srsly... get rid of vars !!!

Answer (score 0):

For LINQ lovers, the same can be achieved using the following two lines:

```
int R = s.GetLength(0), C = s.GetLength(1);
var MyList = Enumerable.Range(0, R).Select(i => i * C).Select(i => s.Cast<string>.Skip(i).Take(C).ToList()).ToList();
```